# If Statement not working, when using elif

Tags: python-3.x, if-statement

No Clue why this doesn't work.

```
Script Below: 
def dirpricker():
    prompt = '<>'
    print("Where do you want to install Deploy in the Current Dir?  (Y/n ")
    Userinput = input(prompt)
    print(Userinput)
    if Userinput == "Y" or "y":
        print("Not Ready Yet!")
    elif Userinput == "N" or "n":
        print("No")
    else:
        print("Please Choose either Yes Or No.")
        print(prompt)
dirpricker()
```

thanks, Matt

**Output**: Not Ready, Even after inputting No.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must write

```
if Userinput == 'Y' or Userinput == 'y':
```

Same for the negative answer.
You can also replace the condition like this:

```
if Userinput.upper() == 'Y':
```

Answer (score 0):

Small mistake in your file, for every condition in the if you have to define what should be true to proceed so instead of `if Userinput == "Y" or "y":` change it to: `if Userinput == "Y" or Userinput == "y":`, `or "y"` is like asking `if "y"` which will evaluate to true.

```
def dirpricker():
    prompt = '>'
    print("Where do you want to install Deploy in the Current Dir?  (Y/n ")
    Userinput = input(prompt)
    print(Userinput)

    if Userinput == "Y" or Userinput == "y":
        print("Not Ready Yet!")
    elif Userinput == "N" or Userinput == "n":
        print("No")
    else:
        print("Please Choose either Yes Or No.")
        print(prompt)

dirpricker()
```

Answer (score 0):

You want to use one of those syntaxes:

```
if Userinput == "Y" or Userinput == "y":
if Userinput in ("Y", "y"):
if Userinput.lower() == "y":
if Userinput.upper() == "Y":
```

Typically, I like to clean up the user input so that spaces and case can be ignored. For example, maybe you want to support things like `" y   "` or `"Y\n"`. In that case you would use an extra line:

```
Userinput = Userinput.lower().strip()
```

and only check

```
if Userinput == "y":
```